# Verifying LEO status online

Tags: police

Is it possible to verify (online) if a Florida neighbor is an active Law enforcement officer? Is there a single agency in which all Florida LEO must register?

The neighbor claims to be a law enforcement officer, however, history indicates that one can not take him at his word.

Comment: Does it have to be online? You could telephone your local precinct and ask if they have an officer X.

Comment: In Florida, there is state, county and city.  The hope is that there is a single registry, preferably online.

Answer (score 3):

Try the phone or email contacts at [Florida Department of Law Enforcement - Home](http://www.fdle.state.fl.us/cms/home.aspx).

The state of Florida doesn't appear to maintain a statewide officer registry, but that department should be able to verify someone is or isn't a officer in conjunction with the police department closest to your location.

If this neighbor is threatening or attempting to enforce the law while not showing ID that proves he/she is an officer, that's serious, and you should call the local police department.

Talking about being a LEO while drinking beer at a BBQ is less serious, but still could be a third degree felony.

See [Statutes & Constitution - Florida State Statutes](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0800-0899/0843/Sections/0843.08.html):

> 843.08 False personation.—A person who falsely assumes or pretends to be a firefighter, sheriff, officer of the Florida Highway Patrol,
>   officer of the Fish and Wildlife Conservation Commission, fire or
>   arson investigator of the Department of Financial Services, officer of
>   the Department of Financial Services, officer of the Department of
>   Corrections, correctional probation officer, deputy sheriff, state
>   attorney or assistant state attorney, statewide prosecutor or
>   assistant statewide prosecutor, state attorney investigator, coroner,
>   police officer, lottery special agent or lottery investigator,
>   beverage enforcement agent, or watchman, or any member of the Florida
>   Commission on Offender Review and any administrative aide or
>   supervisor employed by the commission, or any personnel or
>   representative of the Department of Law Enforcement, or a federal law
>   enforcement officer as defined in s. 901.1505, and takes upon himself
>   or herself to act as such, or to require any other person to aid or
>   assist him or her in a matter pertaining to the duty of any such
>   officer, commits a felony of the third degree,

Answer (score 3):

Usually a District Attorney's or Sheriff's office will keep a list of all active law enforcement officers in their jurisdiction.  However, those lists are treated with extreme discretion because they include the identities of officers on undercover assignments.  For that reason, you cannot generally confirm whether an arbitrary individual is a law enforcement officer.

However, in the case that an individual claims to be an officer, just ask, "Which agency?"  Then call the agency.  Since the individual is clearly not undercover the agency would generally either confirm the claim or else likely be very interested in deterring or prosecuting the false official impersonation.

Comment: I expect that this (having a list) is true for "operating under my authority", but not "residing in my territory". The local sheriff won't have a list of FBI agents, US marshals, Secret Service, military police and so on.

Comment: @user6726: While I don't know of any law requiring this, it is customary for federal agents to alert local law enforcement when they are (or plan to) conduct operations within their jurisdiction.  (Though again, exigent circumstances could prevent this – for example, if there is any concern that advising local LEs of an operation could jeopardize it.)

Comment: Right, but the question seems to be about a guy next door making a claim about his job, so possibly outside the scope of "conducting operations in their jurisdiction".

Comment: @user6726: Yeah, I don't fully understand that angle on the core question.  If somebody "claims to be a law enforcement officer," but otherwise provides no verifiable details ... well, it wouldn't surprise me if somewhere online is a website that for a small fee will deputize you as an officer of the law at the same time it ordains you a religious minister and appoints you to an ambassadorship ;)